# How to get twitter data of tweets within a certain time frame?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

what do I put in my code to make it where I can force the program to stop printing data when the tweets data back to a certain point. For example, how can I get all tweets about Verratti from within a month of running this?

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

access_token = the code
access_token_secret = the code
consumer_key = the code
consumer_secret = the code


#print
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (json.loads(data)['text'])
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

#find
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter         Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:     'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['Verratti'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. It turns out that the Twitter API only lets you look back one week from the current date. There is a way around it though, someone made a github library that can search for any timeframe using twitter's advanced search function and you don't even have to bother with the whole authentication process.

Check it out: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python